# JavaScript Websocket based upon ActionScript XMLsocket

Tags: javascript, sockets, actionscript

Since Flash player is not supported any more I had to recreate a dynamic video that I've made years ago.
The setup is running on Windows and there is a Mediator app which gathers information and send them to my video app via XMLsocket.
In ActionScript it was working like this:

```
  var xml_s=new XMLSocket();
  xml_s.connect("127.0.0.1", 51000);
  xml_s.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT,xmlsocket);
  //OnConnect//;
  xml_s.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE,xmlsocket);
  //OnDisconnect//;
  xml_s.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,xmlsocket);
  //Unable To Connect// ;
  
  function xmlsocket(e) {
    switch (e.type) {
        case 'ioError' :
            outputMsg.text="Unable to Connect"
            break;
        case 'connect' :
            outputMsg.text="Connected"
            break;
        case 'close' :
            outputMsg.text="OnDisconnect"
            break;
    }
  }
```

But in JavaScript something like this, gives back an immediate Error - connection failed

```
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:51000");

socket.onopen = function(e) {
  alert("[open] Connection established");
  alert("Sending to server");
  socket.send("My name is John");
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  alert(`[message] Data received from server: ${event.data}`);
};

socket.onclose = function(event) {
  if (event.wasClean) {
    alert(`[close] Connection closed cleanly, code=${event.code} reason=${event.reason}`);
  } else {
    // e.g. server process killed or network down
    // event.code is usually 1006 in this case
    alert('[close] Connection died');
  }
};

socket.onerror = function(error) {
  alert(`[error] ${error.message}`);
};
```

The new video app is front-end based and looks best in Chrome.
What's an issue here? Are there some Windows based restrictions? How can I fix it?

Comment: And your local server is running ok? It can be pinged from CMD window?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not my local server - I can only access it through a TeamViewer. The old Flash generated .exe is connecting but they can't use it because it slows down drastically over a couple of hours.

Comment: **XMLSocket** is a **TCP** socket (which is additionally limited to sending/receiving 0-terminated **XML** strings), while **WebSocket** is something like *persistent full-duplex connection over HTTP*, I'm not into technical specifics (please figure it out by yourself), but I believe they are different in terms of protocol, that's why your connection fails upon handshake. Having that, I googled a bit and it seems that there's no legit way for **JS** to connect to a raw **TCP** socket directly. That means, you'll probably need a proxy server application in between.